# Cannot get rJava to work properly in MacOS 10.14

Tags: java, r, sympy, rjava

I am trying to code using the rSymPy package. When I type in library(rSymPy) I get the following warnings:

```
> library(rSymPy)
Loading required package: rJython
Loading required package: rJava
Loading required package: rjson
Warning messages:
1: package ‘rJava’ was built under R version 3.4.4 
2: package ‘rjson’ was built under R version 3.4.4
```

This is fine because in theory my code should still work. However, when I try running my function which uses the sympy() command I get the following error:

```
> moment_generating_function(12)
Show Traceback

Error in .jcheck() : No running JVM detected. Maybe .jinit() would help.
```

I then run .jinit() which produces no output. Running my code again, I now get the following error

```
 Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Z", "hasField", .jcast(x, "java/lang/Object"),  : 
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have tried reinstalling my JDK and tried running "r cmd javareconf;" in my terminal multiple times. I would just code this directly in Python but unfortunately my assignment requires I use the rSymPy package in R. I would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Comment: derogatory comments citing python aren't great ways to engender aid from R folk.

Comment: You have not described the installation of JDK with any detail at all. Nor have you described your R version with any detail, other than to include a warning.

Comment: java -version
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: Also I don't mean to be derogatory to R. When I say "unfortunately", I mean that based on the problem it just seems that it would be far easier and more practical just to code directly in Python rather than trying to meld the two together.

Comment: with most recent macOS it might be you have to go through compilation hell ;) Take a look here: http://www.owsiak.org/r-3-4-rjava-macos-and-even-more-mess/